# How to recursively sum parent/child hierarchy

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a data table that looks like this:

```
UnitID  UnitParentID    ScoreCount  ScoreSum   Level
7112                       72          292       1 
7120    7112               72          308       2
7139    7112               24           82       2 
7150    7112              166          586       2
23682   7112              104          414       2
7100    7112              272         1016       2
23691   7112               94          300       2
23696   7112               24           80       2
23700   23696             184          594       3
23694   23691              24           64       3
23689   7120               88          390       3
7148    23696             112          420       3
7126    7120               32          132       3
7094    7120               96          332       3
7098    7094               64          240       4
23687   7094               16           62       4
```

What I'm looking to do is recursively add from the lowest hierarchy up to the highest so that the numbers below roll up into their parent.  So a parent would add to its existing values any children, up the tree to the top.

In this example, the last two rows would stay unchanged because they have no children.  Unit ID 7094 would have a scorecount of 96 (base) + 64 + 16 (2 children) for a new total of 176 (and the same logic for scoresum).  The others at level 3 would stay unchanged because they have no children.  I believe I need to start at the bottom so that the layers above will have the correct values for any children.

If someone could point me to a good source where I could learn how to accomplish this, I'd be very greatful.

Comment: You could use a recursive CTE

Comment: Post up an example output

Comment: The first answer to the question I flagged as duplicate should work for you. I won't post the solution as an answer because I adapted it from the linked post but anyway: adapted to your table and data as working solution: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/71409/1

Answer (score 0):

WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 7112 unitid , NULL UnitParentId,72 ScoreCount,292 ScoreSum,1 Level UNION ALL
    SELECT 7120 unitid ,7112 UnitParentId,72 ScoreCount,308 ScoreSum,2 Level UNION ALL
    SELECT 7139 unitid ,7112 UnitParentId,24 ScoreCount,82 ScoreSum,2 Level UNION ALL
    SELECT 7150 unitid ,7112 UnitParentId,166 ScoreCount,586 ScoreSum,2 Level UNION ALL
    SELECT 23682 unitid ,7112 UnitParentId,104 ScoreCount,414 ScoreSum,2 Level UNION ALL
    SELECT 7100 unitid ,7112 UnitParentId,272 ScoreCount,1016 ScoreSum,2 Level UNION ALL
    SELECT 23691 unitid ,7112 UnitParentId,94 ScoreCount,300 ScoreSum,2 Level UNION ALL
    SELECT 23696 unitid ,7112 UnitParentId,24 ScoreCount,80 ScoreSum,2 Level UNION ALL
    SELECT 23700 unitid ,23696 UnitParentId,184 ScoreCount,594 ScoreSum,3 Level UNION ALL
    SELECT 23694 unitid ,23691 UnitParentId,24 ScoreCount,64 ScoreSum,3 Level UNION ALL
    SELECT 23689 unitid ,7120 UnitParentId,88 ScoreCount,390 ScoreSum,3 Level UNION ALL
    SELECT 7148 unitid ,23696 UnitParentId,112 ScoreCount,420 ScoreSum,3 Level UNION ALL
    SELECT 7126 unitid ,7120 UnitParentId,32 ScoreCount,132 ScoreSum,3 Level UNION ALL
    SELECT 7094 unitid ,7120 UnitParentId,96 ScoreCount,332 ScoreSum,3 Level UNION ALL
    SELECT 7098 unitid ,7094 UnitParentId,64 ScoreCount,240 ScoreSum,4 Level UNION ALL
    SELECT 23687 unitid ,7094 UnitParentId,16 ScoreCount,62 ScoreSum,4 Level 
),
RECURSIVECTE AS
(
SELECT unitid,   CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),convert(nvarchar(20),unitid)) PARENTLIST, ScoreCount
FROM CTE 
WHERE UnitParentId IS NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT C.unitid,  CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),convert(nvarchar(20),R.PARENTLIST) + ',' + convert(nvarchar(20),C.unitid)), C.ScoreCount
FROM RECURSIVECTE R
INNER JOIN CTE C ON R.unitid = C.UnitParentId
)

SELECT C.unitid, R.ScoreCount 
FROM CTE C
CROSS APPLY
            (
                SELECT SUM(ScoreCount) ScoreCount
                FROM RECURSIVECTE R
                WHERE CHARINDEX(convert(nvarchar(20),C.UNITID), R.PARENTLIST,0) > 0
            ) R